# Not able to write Data in Parquet File using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming:

```
val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("subscribe", "topic")
      .load()
```

I want to write data to FileSystem using DataStreamWriter,

```
val query = df
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("parquet")
          .start("data")
```

But zero files are getting created in `data` folder. Only `_spark_metadata` is getting created.

However, I can see the data on console when `format` is `console`:

```
val query = df
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("console")
          .start()

+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                time|              col1|              col2|
+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
|49368-05-11 20:42...|0.9166470338147503|0.5576946794171861|
+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I cannot understand the reason behind it.

Spark - 2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Actually when I tried to run the Structured Streaming on `spark-shell`, then it gave an error that `endingOffsets` are not valid in streaming queries, i.e.,:

```
val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("subscribe", "topic")
      .load()


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ending offset not valid in streaming queries
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$$anonfun$validateStreamOptions$1.apply(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:374)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$$anonfun$validateStreamOptions$1.apply(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:373)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.sourceSchema(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:199)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:124)
  ... 48 elided
```

So, I removed `endingOffsets` from streaming query.

```
val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("subscribe", "topic")
      .load()
```

Then I tried to save streaming queries' result in Parquet files, during which I came to know that - checkpoint location must be specified, i.e.,:

```
val query = df
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("parquet")
          .start("data")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...);
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:207)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:204)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:203)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:269)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:262)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:206)
  ... 48 elided
```

So, I added `checkPointLocation`:

```
val query = df
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("parquet")
          .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
          .start("data")
```

After doing these modifications, I was able to save streaming queries' results in Parquet files.

But, it is strange that when I ran the same code via `sbt` application, it didn't threw any errors, but when I ran the same code via `spark-shell` these errors were thrown. I think Apache Spark should throw these errors when run via `sbt`/`maven` app too. It is seems to be a bug to me !

Comment: Structured Streaming doesn't have any special logic for `sbt` or `spark-shell`. I believe the problem is in how you run the application using `sbt/maven`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you are using `spark-submit` to run it, you will see the same error like `spark-shell`.

Comment: No, I am using `sbt run` to run the application.

Comment: I tried `sbt run` and it worked as expected. I can see the error from `sbt run`'s output. How's your codes when using sbt?

Comment: By the way, please make sure you use Spark 2.1.1 in your sbt file.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.0 in my sbt file. Is this feature, of throwing exception, not present on Spark 2.1.0 ?

Comment: If you want to use batch Kafka source, it's not in 2.1.0. So if you are using Spark 2.1.0 in sbt and run `sbt run`, it will just use Spark 2.1.0. Then it doesn't know the `endingOffsets` option and will just ignore it.

Comment: Oh ok! I didn't knew that. Thanks for the info. I have added the Spark version in my question, so, that everyone can know about this issue in Spark 2.1.0's Structured Streaming.

Comment: looks like you can't specify `latest` for `endingOffsets`, this might be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem but for different reasons, posting here in case someone has the same issue.  When writing your output stream to file in append mode with watermarking, structured streaming has an interesting behavior where it won't actually write any data until a time bucket is older than the watermark time.  If you're testing structured streaming and have an hour long water mark, you won't see any output for at least an hour.

Comment: That's how append mode works and guarantee the semantic, so it works as expected.

Comment: Yes I agree the behavior is correct, it's just easy to get tripped up on this when using structured streaming for the first time.